# Tangent, condition

Tags: c++, trigonometry, conditional-statements

How to bypass the angles at which the function tan (x) is not defined, ie x != Pi/2 + k * PI ?

I tried to use the condition:

```
(x != 0) && (2 * x / M_PI - (int)(2 * x / M_PI ) ) < epsilon,
```

but it represents a condition

x != Pi/2 + k * PI / 2.

Thanx for your help.

Comment: Also note that some mathematical algorithms may require the value of tangent, when `cos(x) = 0` - you may want to implement your own variant of `tan(x)`, which would yield something like `numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` for that case.

Answer (score 4):

The same condition can be used to determine which values of cos(x) will be zero. Thanks to that wonderful fact, you can simply do the following (pseudocode):

```
SafeTan(x)
{
    if (cos(x) < epsilon) { /* handle the error */ }
    else { return tan(x); }
}
```

**Edit:** As [In silico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308661/in-silico) points out, this is a result of the trigonometric identity:

[tan(x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions) = [sin(x) / cos(x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Trigonometric_functions)

In this form, you can see that the undefined values will appear wherever cos(x) = 0 because of the division by zero.

Comment: This works because `tan(x) = sin(x) / cos(x)`. When `cos(x)` is zero the tangent will be undefined. Of course we use an epsilon here because we're working with floating point.

Comment: +1 simplify the maths first, then a simple program will follow

Answer (score 0):

How about trying

```
(x - PI/2) % PI != 0
```

Will find check for the values of x that cause tan(x) to be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use tangent? It can be more performant than using a (sine, cosine) pair, but usually you can use a (sine, cosine) pair without worrying about discontinuities.

What are you using tangent for?